# Consultar aniversariantes do mês atual em SQL

Tags: sql

Preciso efetuar uma consulta de aniversariante do mês corrente. Mas gostaria que fosse automático, e não precisar digitar o mês. Abaixo tem o exemplo que fiz, digitando o mês.

OBS: o meu campo é *dt_nasc (TIMESTAMP)*.

```
SELECT * from top_007 where extract(month from dt_nasc)='9'; //referente ao mes 9
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: É postgres ou outro banco?

Comment: Para uma resposta conclusiva é necessário informar o `SGBD` utilizado

Comment: É mysql ou outro banco?

Answer (score 4):

Use a função `now()` combinada com `month()` para pegar o mês atual.

```
SELECT * from top_007 where month(dt_nasc) = month(now())
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso seja SQL SERVER  o comando seria assim:

```
SELECT * from top_007 where MONTH(dt_nasc) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Comment: Creio que `extract` é uma função do MySql, então a pergunta deve ser de fato sobre mysql. Infelizmente tem muitos usuários que usam a tag [tag:sql] para se referir ao mysql :/ e acaba gerando esses problemas de entendimento.